# IIS - Create a local host name and use it

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm new to IIS and I'm trying to use a local hostname to differentiate my web projects. Basically, what I want is to do something like:

http://myproject.dev

and access it directly via the web.

Normally, with an Apache server, I would create a virtualhost and I would add an entry in my hosts file.

So, I tried to do the same with IIS. I created a a website as follows:

[image]

In my hostfile, I then added an entry:

```
127.0.0.1   myproject.dev
```

However, when I type the address, I'm redirected to my IP Address and I can't see the website.

Am I missing something?

Edit 1:
[image]

Comment: before editing the host file, does going to http://localhost opens your website?

Comment: No it says not found, 404 error.

Comment: so the problem in the host name, just focus on why it is not working before editing host file, seams a problem in your website or IIS website configurations apart from host name

Comment: Ok, but in IIS, it is expecting to return the website only if it matches the host name so in theory, it is expected that the website will not work by typing localhost?

Comment: Yes, http://localhost will work with your defaultwebsite on IIS website, you can use a different port for the new website or may be make your website the default one

Comment: Do I absolutely need to use a new port? I'm saying that because in Apache, I can easily keep the port 80 but having different local hostname that I access my websites with.

Comment: yes, in IIS too, you can have multiple host name, I just wanted you to test the website without host name because seams that the problem is not in the host name, it is something wrong with the website or its IIS configurations, is this a website you can open in VS so you use the VS integrated server instead of IIS just for testing?

Comment: I just don't get how typing localhost would bring up my website though. Currently, my website is configured in IIS to return the content if the hostname is myproject.dev. So, if I'm not misunderstanding anything, typing localhost should in fact not bring any website since my only website is myproject.dev and it is not configured to return when the ip address is entered.

Comment: Yes, you are right, based on your current configurations, what I was saying is to try and remove the host name, I am saying that because i see that your current configurations are correct.

Comment: Ok so what I meant is that yes my website is working if I don't put any hostname.

Comment: does your host file contain any other records? which may conflict with this one

Comment: No, it only has  127.0.0.1       localhost

Comment: And when writing http://myproject.dev are you getting an error or just empty page?

Comment: I have a redirect to my ip address (caused by the hosts file) and yes I have an error because IIS is expecting an host name. If I remove the host name in IIS then yes I can see my website.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? sorry asking too much but trying to help

Comment: hey no problem, thanks to you. I'm getting a 404 since IIS cannot find any website listening to only port 80 without hostname. However, if I remove the hostname myproject.dev in IIS then I can see my site just fine but that's not what I want since I will have many different sites.

Comment: I can't get why this may happen, I have a website here with the same config as yours and it is working fine, is it possible to send me a screenshot from the whole iis window? may be i get something easy to fix

Comment: I updated the post with the complete screenshot and with the hosts file

Comment: You do realize this connection would only work locally? If someone in another city on another network wanted to view your site then you would have to get a public IP for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aha, I got it, it is host file issue, just remove:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

or comment it because it make everything go back to 127.0.0.1

and write yours like this:

```
127.0.0.1 myproject.dev
```

Comment: Oh god no I forgot that I'm on a company computer and the proxy is causing the issue!! I'm so sorry to have made you lost your time, but I finally figured it out! I have to add my domain name in the proxy exceptions...

Answer (score -1):

You just have to create a folder in c: --> inetpub --> wwwroot than just type localhost/yourprojectfolder..

Comment: no, this is not a requirement, you can create the website folder anywhere on your machine and just point to it from IIS

Comment: The problem is that I want to access my website the following way: http://myproject.dev not using localhost